# How to use flex to create a person

Tags: apache-flex, algorithm

Based on user input height, weight, measurements and other data, dynamically generate a person (can produce 3D graphics?, if you can please tell me how to do)
Who can tell the specific technology, if can please tell me some reference material.

Comment: I'm thinking "Weird Science" ;)

Comment: `:s/fl/s/` Sorry, couldn't resist ;)

Answer (score 1):

Flex doesn't support "True" 3D, at least not yet.  There is speculation that the next version of the Flash Player should support some form of 3D.

You can do "Faux" 3D stuff with PaperVision or Away3D.  The Flash Player also has some similar "Faux" 3D stuff built in, but all my experiments have related to rotating items and the sort.

I suspect you'll be better suited with some type of 3D modeling tool, and not trying to do this in the Flash Player.